# Error installing gevent in Docker Alpine Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to install gevent on docker image `python:3.8.0a4-alpine3.9` which is running gunicorn.

When building the docker, I always get an error "gcc failed with exit status 1".

I've tried installing several packages but none have worked.

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.0a4-alpine3.9

RUN echo "@edge-community http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
  apk update && \
  apk add build-base python-dev && \
  apk add py-gevent

RUN pip install gunicorn gevent
```

command:
`docker build . -t "test:one"`

Last few lines of output:

```sh
  /usr/local/include/python3.8/code.h:105:28: note: expected 'PyObject *' {aka 'struct _object *'} but argument is of type 'int'
   PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
                              ^~~~~~~~~~
  src/gevent/libev/corecext.c:21340:9: warning: passing argument 15 of 'PyCode_New' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
           __pyx_empty_bytes  /*PyObject *lnotab*/
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  src/gevent/libev/corecext.c:373:79: note: in definition of macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
             PyCode_New(a, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
                                                                                 ^~~~
  In file included from /usr/local/include/python3.8/compile.h:5,
                   from /usr/local/include/python3.8/Python.h:137,
                   from src/gevent/libev/corecext.c:63:
  /usr/local/include/python3.8/code.h:105:28: note: expected 'int' but argument is of type 'PyObject *' {aka 'struct _object *'}
   PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
                              ^~~~~~~~~~
  src/gevent/libev/corecext.c:373:11: error: too few arguments to function 'PyCode_New'
             PyCode_New(a, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
             ^~~~~~~~~~
  src/gevent/libev/corecext.c:21325:15: note: in expansion of macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
       py_code = __Pyx_PyCode_New(
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  In file included from /usr/local/include/python3.8/compile.h:5,
                   from /usr/local/include/python3.8/Python.h:137,
                   from src/gevent/libev/corecext.c:63:
  /usr/local/include/python3.8/code.h:105:28: note: declared here
   PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
                              ^~~~~~~~~~
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gevent
  Running setup.py clean for gevent

...
lots of stuff
...


out a cast [-Wint-conversion]
             __pyx_empty_bytes  /*PyObject *lnotab*/
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/gevent/libev/corecext.c:373:79: note: in definition of macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
               PyCode_New(a, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
                                                                                   ^~~~
    In file included from /usr/local/include/python3.8/compile.h:5,
                     from /usr/local/include/python3.8/Python.h:137,
                     from src/gevent/libev/corecext.c:63:
    /usr/local/include/python3.8/code.h:105:28: note: expected 'int' but argument is of type 'PyObject *' {aka 'struct _object *'}
     PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
                                ^~~~~~~~~~
    src/gevent/libev/corecext.c:373:11: error: too few arguments to function 'PyCode_New'
               PyCode_New(a, k, l, s, f, code, c, n, v, fv, cell, fn, name, fline, lnos)
               ^~~~~~~~~~
    src/gevent/libev/corecext.c:21325:15: note: in expansion of macro '__Pyx_PyCode_New'
         py_code = __Pyx_PyCode_New(
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In file included from /usr/local/include/python3.8/compile.h:5,
                     from /usr/local/include/python3.8/Python.h:137,
                     from src/gevent/libev/corecext.c:63:
    /usr/local/include/python3.8/code.h:105:28: note: declared here
     PyAPI_FUNC(PyCodeObject *) PyCode_New(
                                ^~~~~~~~~~
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-3i9v17bs/gevent/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-gnyfyggo/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-3i9v17bs/gevent/
```

Here is the Gunicorn command I am running:

```
gunicorn web.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000  --worker-connections 1000 --workers 6 -k gevent
```

Do you have any ideas on how to install Gevent with this version of python alpine?

Edit -
It installs successfully on the last version of Alpine and python - `FROM python:3.7-alpine3.8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1019), years ago, guys want to install on python3.7 and encountered issue, and fix was made on last year to make `gevent` support python3.7.

So, I guess gevent team need additional effort to adapt to every python version as its principle is to make some `monkey patch` for python.

And, from its current [official announcement](http://www.gevent.org/install.html#supported-platforms), it said:

> gevent 1.5 runs on Python 2.7.9 and up, and Python 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7.

It did not mention 3.8, so definitely you need to wait.

Comment: For those who like me reached this post looking for a fix for failed build on a windows machine, don't ignore the Notice about windows in the official announcement link. _It won't build on your windows machine if its not already_, have a good day!

Answer (score 15):

ailpine image need install below libs to build gevent.
`RUN apk add --no-cache python3-dev libffi-dev gcc musl-dev make`
[this docker file](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1567) may help to test

Comment: Thank you sir! I was missing make, on alpine 3.7.7. For anyone wondering at this time of writing python 3.8 is not supported for gevent, no matter alpine or not. If you are using a a docker builder image, make sure you put both images in the dockerfile on the same version :)

Comment: This helped me even though I did not use that image. Using `python:3.6.5-slim` gevent would fail. I added the above requirements as well as `libevent-dev` and the install passes.

Answer (score 5):

To me none of the above worked with `python:3.8-alpine`. Worked this:

```
RUN apk --update --no-cache add python3-dev libffi-dev gcc musl-dev make libevent-dev build-base
```

Comment: I tried to reduce the list and finally, only `build-base` is required.

Comment: just add build-base. worked for me on python:3.8.10-alpine3.13

Answer (score 2):

I am using `gevent==21.1.2` with `python:3.9.4-alpine` by adding

```
RUN apk update \
   && apk add --no-cache build-base
```

It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

**Good news:** As of gevent 21.12.0 (released 2021-12-11), there is a musllinux image on pypi, so there are no missing dependencies and it will install from wheel. Verified on python3.10-alpine that `pip install gevent` works fine. Woohoo!

Historical answer, see below.

---

Just adding on here: for python:3.9-alpine (which is currently python3.9.9 + alpine 3.14.3), I needed the following for Gevent 21.1.0:

`RUN apk add --no-cache build-base libffi-dev`

Hopefully they add support for installing on Alpine via pip since there is a recent PEP that should make this easier. I opened an issue here: https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1837